# type hints and reflexive relations

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I'm enjoying Python 3.5 **type hints** support, but facing a special concern.

I'm trying to specify the type of a constructor parameter, which should be the class itself (i.e. a *self-referential relation*). Here is my example:

```
class Section(object):    
    def __init__(self, path: str, parent: Section):
        pass
```

Python complains with a

```
NameError: name 'Section' is not defined
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: use an abstract base class to avoid self reference? this may also avoid circular referencing that could cause memory issues (or it may not, ymmv)